# Querying multiple Azure TSI time series instances over same search span in single query

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

We have an Azure time series insights environment that contains multiple time series that are accessible via their `timeSeriesName`.

Using the information from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/preview-query). I was able to query the time series I created, but only one at a time.

By looping over the different time series names, I was able to aggregate the events as well, but unfortunately, this method is not efficient enough for our intended purpose.

I am therefore trying to query multiple time series instances from the same Azure Time Series Insights environment in a single query (i.e. multiple time series names). No such method is provided in the documentation.

The data is intended to be ingested as a batch by an application, that will run various machine learning operations on it. Both of the following queries work as intended, but only for one time series at a time.

```
body1 = {
    "getEvents": {
        "timeSeriesName" : "name123",
        "searchSpan": {
            "from":  "2017-03-08T00:00:00Z",
            "to":  "2017-03-08T00:05:00Z"
        }
    }
}

body2 = {
    "getSeries" :{
        "timeSeriesName" : "name123",
        "searchSpan": {
            "from":  "2017-03-08T00:00:00Z",
            "to":  "2017-03-08T00:05:00Z"
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be something of the form:

> {'timestamps': ['2017-03-08T00:00:00Z', '2017-03-08T00:01:00Z', '2017-03-08T00:02:00Z', '2017-03-08T00:03:00Z', '2017-03-08T00:04:00Z'], 'properties': ["name123": {'values': [5.1, 6.3, 7.6, 4.5, 3.3], 'name': 'Temperature', 'type': 'Double'}, "name987": {'values': [13.5, 15.7, 12.1,  9.7, 8.5], 'name': 'Temperature', 'type': 'Double'}]